# Automount usb and run a script

Tags: linux, usb, debian, mount

I am looking forward to automount `ANY` USB on plugin and running a shell script on my raspberry pi running raspbian wheezy. I have installed `usbmount` for automounting and I followed these steps:

```
3. Now is time to create your UDEV rule:

sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/85-my_rule.rules

4. And add the text

ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device",RUN+="usr/bin/local/script.sh"
```

I have created a shellscript script.sh in `/usr/bin/local` that currently has only an echo statement and given a+x permissions to it. However, this much doesn't work when the USB is plugged in. It gets automounted but the script doesnt run and nothing echoes on my terminal. (I am SSHing into my pi from laptop).

Any ideas where things are breaking? :)

Comment: I suggest asking this in http://www.stackoverflow.com, or maybe not, i don't think anyone here would be able to answer such a technical question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo there; it should read: RUN+="/usr/bin/local/script.sh".
Other than that, it looks fine!